# Opening a word dotm template through vba and need doc 1 to have vba code same as template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have developed a word document log book. the user forms ask question's in order to mark certain sections Not applicable and then delete the section contents so log book is bespoke to site.

I would really like to keep the master un corrupted by users and have tried the add.docuement method but this just opens a new document as doc 1 with all the log book content but no VBA code. Is there way to open a new doc with the VBA code included?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there isn't. Look at the new document's `AttachedTemplate` property, however. It points to the template with the code, and that code is available while the reference is. In other words, if you provide the user with a template and he creates a new document from that template that new document will be able to use all the code in the template while it remains on the same machine and the `AttachedTemplate` property isn't removed.

However, once the link between document and AttachedTemplate is broken, by whichever method, the functionality also ceases. This is so by design. The only way to pass actual code with a document is by adding the code to the document itself and distributing copies of that document which would include the code.

Comment: will look into attached template